# PowerBI dashboard not importing all records

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to PowerBI and am running into the following problem:

When creating a powerbi data import it doesn't import all the records from the database.

My setup is Azure SQL Database with 37138 records in a table.
Only 20001 records showing in my dashboard.

Any idea what the limitation could be?
I removed 3 varchar(max) colums. that increased my records from 2519 to 20xxx. My database contains 37138  records.

How can I retrieve all records?

Answer (score 2):

You can import up to 5 million rows per table, up to 1 GB of data per dataset. But I have doubts it will be wise move. For 5 million rows you may want to consider direct query mode instead.
Please, provide more information about your import process and how you count the number of rows in both places, if you want to get an answer about that part of your question too.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem.

I forgot I had a filter on a table which I forgot.

removed the filter and I see all the records!